# Phpmailer apresenta erro SMTP

Tags: php, phpmailer

Estou rodando os códigos do phpmailer e o seguinte aviso de erro surge:

> Fatal error: Class 'SMTP' not found in public_html/php/phpmailer/class.phpmailer.php on line 1291

Alguém pode me ajudar?

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

Comment: O arquivo `class.smtp.php` está na mesma pasta que o `PHPMailerAutoload.php` ?

Comment: Sim, está! Peguei do github do site do phpmailer.
Como posso postar imagem aqui?

Comment: Clique em `editar` da sua pergunta, lá tem um botão com icone de imagem!

Comment: Veja na imagem, está tudo junto.

Comment: Você conferiu se está igual à https://github.com/PHPMailer/PHPMailer/blob/master/examples/mail.phps ?

Comment: Não!
Peguei o código, mas não sabia tem que estar igual a esse código.
Achei que fosse só pegar o código e ajustar com meus dados.

Comment: Agora deixei o código com o do link que vc mandou e essa mensagem pareceu.

Warning: file_get_contents(contents.html) [function.file-get-contents]: failed to open stream: No such file or directory in /home/petsm976/public_html/php/parceiros.php on line 383

Comment: Então, este é só um exemplo, tem muitas coisas que você não irá precisar com esta linha que está causando o seu erro `$mail->msgHTML(file_get_contents('contents.html'), dirname(__FILE__));`

Comment: E como eu coloco conteúdo, texto no email, pois agora aparece isso:
Mailer Error: Message body empty

Comment: Ao invés de `$mail->msgHTML(file_get_contents('contents.html'), dirname(__FILE__));` o correto seria `$mail->msgHTML("Meu código <strong> em negrito</strong>");`

Comment: Consegui, troquei como vc disse.
Mas e pq será que eu não consigo usar o outro código, pq será que dá esse problema de SMTP?

Comment: Acho que é a localização das pastas...então enviou certinho?

Comment: @FelipeDouradinho, consegui fazer funcionar, mas só agora que eu subi minha aplicação para um servidor.
Rodar local, não teve jeito.
Value mesmo assim.

Comment: Opa, imagina haha

Answer (score 1):

O caminho está errado, procure a linha com erro, e apague o começo que deve ser `phpmailer/class.phpmailer.php`, deixa somente `class.phpmailer.php`.

Answer (score -1):

Olá,

A função SMTP não esta sendo encontrada na patch do seu arquivo php:

> public_html/php/phpmailer/class.phpmailer.php

Recomendo analisar a linha 1291 no arquivo acima para obter mais detalhes sobre o código e possivelmente resolver o erro, certifique-se de que seu phpmailer esteja corretamente compilado.